# How to output the content of this list in certain order?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of Record,

```
List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

I want to output the content of records into a CSV file with 3 columns, but want the rows in the output order of cid, as below:

```
  cid     cname    spu
  001     Book     23a
  001     Book     24a
  001     Book     13c
  002     Music    2f
  002     Music    24g
  002     Music    24a
```

...

The order of row 001 and 002 in the list are mixed, so they are not ordered. I need to output them to a file:

```
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter("file.txt");
  for(Record record : records){
      writer.write(record)
   }
```

How to achieve this?

```
class Record{

    protected String cid;
    protected String cname;
    protected String spu;

    public Record(String cid, String cname, String spu) {

        this.cid = cid;
        this.cname = cname;
        this.spu = spu;
    }
}
```

Comment: `records.stream().sorted(r -> r.cid).forEach(writer::write);`

Comment: I am using Java 7. Sorry.